# Who pays for TAs?

Tags: funding, teaching-assistant

A TA normally has a hourly contract for working with a professor. Who pays for this contract? The professor's external funding is for research, not education.

If the department pays for that, how the budget is distributed among professors, as every professor (almost any) would appreciate having TA.

Comment: There are many problems with this statement. TA's are not paid an hourly wage; they are expected to work a certain number of hours per week on teaching. There's a big difference between these two ideas. Moreover, in some places, some of the funding given to the professor by the university __is__ for teaching, not for research.

Comment: @aeismail I said normally (i.e., mostly). Though, it was not the key point in the question. Sorry, I meant external funding, not university funding.

Comment: But neither an RA contract nor a TA contract is hourly. They receive a stipend or a salary, not an hourly wage.

Comment: @aeismail I meant they are not employees with fixed salary, they get paid based on the hours of working like adjunct professors.

Comment: @user13854: Neither of those is accurate in my experience.  TAs usually do receive a fixed salary.  There may be policies dictating a maximum number of hours that a TA should be assigned to work, but they get paid the same even if they complete their duties in less time.  Adjunct professors also get paid a fixed amount per course that they teach; the number of hours they actually spend working does not affect their pay.

Answer (score 7):

Your question makes assumptions that are not necessarily valid.

For instance, in the US (where I studied), the contracts for TA's are normally paid for at the departmental level. The department gets a budget from the university to cover a certain amount of TA's, which it allocates to the different courses taught in the department, usually based on the expected enrollment. Courses that have traditionally enrolled more students (usually intro classes) as well as lab courses tend to have more TA's than smaller, more specialized courses.

By contrast, in Germany, the expectation is that the individual professors' research groups are responsible for providing the funding for teaching assistants. In part, this is done through the contribution of faculty-wide teaching resources, as well as having permanent positions called *Planstelle* which have teaching duties associated with them. So the money in large part still comes from the faculty, but the organization process is at the scale of an individual group.

Comment: where was my assumption? I asked A or B, and you answered both!

Comment: The assumption that it's an hourly contract, and that the professor's budget is only research-related (which is not always true, as I've shown).

Comment: The TA contract (in my institution) is negotiated based on the average number of hours per week to handle teaching duties. The maximum number of hours is capped based on the expected term load and can range from 0.25 full-time equivalents or 1.0 FTE. The salary is paid by the department, but there is an average hourly wage built in to the contract cost. In my institution, this wage rate is set by the university, but it may be set by departments at other institutions. I've never heard of a professor paying directly for a TA.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's a function of how the system is set up. In Germany, it's done at the level of the professor. This is likely not the case in most other countries.

Answer (score 3):

In the schools with which I am familiar,the *department* pays for all teaching activities, including Teaching Assistants.

Comment: Of course, in the end the hard cash probably comes from a university account. But I am also most familiar with a situation where the department is given a certain budget by the university, and they pay TAs from that budget. So the department has the decision-making authority, but the actual money still comes from the university.

Answer (score 1):

In Sweden, PhD students and Post docs are paid with the PI research money for doing research. Teaching is optional (but in some departments it is expected or strongly encouraged), in which case it is paid from the department's teaching budget.